# Scipy null_space does not give me the correct answer

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a problem with Scipy null_space. Take the following example:

```
A = np.array([[7,3,2],[3,9,4],[2,4,5]])
eigen = np.linalg.eig(A)
```

with output eigen =

```
(array([13.477,  5.   ,  2.523]), 
array([[ 0.486,  0.873, -0.041],
       [ 0.74 , -0.436, -0.511],
       [ 0.464, -0.218,  0.858]]))
```

I have the eigenvalues and eigenvectors inside *eigen* tuple. Now if `e` is an eigenvalue of `A` (for example 13.477), obviously the nullspace of 
`A - e I` should not be empty, however:

```
null = la.null_space(A-eigen[0][0]*np.eye(3))
```

returns

```
array([], shape=(3, 0), dtype=complex128)
```

which should've been the eigenvector corresponding to `eigen[0][0]` (Note that when I run the same code for `eigen[0][1]` and `eigen[0][2]` it correctly returns the eigenvectors we saw above).
To check this, I asked for eigenvalues and eigenvectors of `(A-eI)` :

```
null_eigen = np.linalg.eig(A-eigen[0][0]*np.eye(3))
```

with output null_eigen =

```
(array([-1.243e-14, -8.477e+00, -1.095e+01]), 
 array([[ 0.486,  0.873, -0.041],
        [ 0.74 , -0.436, -0.511],
        [ 0.464, -0.218,  0.858]]))
```

clearly the first eigenvalue, which corresponds to the eigenvector of 13.477, is "almost" zero, but why is it that scipy.linalg.null_space did not pick it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`null_space`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.null_space.html),

> `rcond` : Relative condition number. Singular values s smaller than `rcond * max(s)` are considered zero. Default: `floating point eps * max(M,N)`.

and thus `rcond` determines the effective null space. Floating point math is not exact and so for the eigenvalues this happens to slip above the threshold. Using a larger number for `rcond` will give the expected result:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import null_space

A = np.array([[7, 3, 2],
              [3, 9, 4],
              [2, 4, 5]])
eigen = np.linalg.eig(A)
print(eigen[1][:, 0])
print(null_space(A - eigen[0][0]*np.eye(3), rcond=1e-14))
```

with the output:

```
[0.48622704 0.74041411 0.46407996]
[[-0.48622704]
 [-0.74041411]
 [-0.46407996]]
```

For more details you can also take a look [at the source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/802f4eac0eadd6c1372b0cf6c04d97ea26c00c57/scipy/linalg/decomp_svd.py#L384).